# Return distinct clients with specific year or null

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering how could I select people who enrolled in the 2016-2017 school year, and whose school year is unknown(null). Also, since I want to update dataset for every people (each row per person) who have been shown in the tutoring program, if the school year of that person is neither 2016-2017 nor null, I also want to return the lasted year s/he has shown. Plus, I would like to extract the date they first started the program.

sample input:

```
id  event_name  actual_date  is_noshow  school_year  
1   tutoring    2016/01/01   FALSE      2016-2017
1   tutoring    2016/09/01   FALSE      2016-2017
2   tutoring                 TRUE       
3   tutoring    2016/02/02   FALSE      2016-2017
4   tutoring                 FALSE      NULL
5   tutoring    2013/01/01   FALSE      2013-2014
```

sample output:

```
id  event_name  first_day    is_noshow  school_year  
1   tutoring    2016/01/01   FALSE      2016-2017
3   tutoring    2016/02/02   FALSE      2016-2017
4   tutoring                 FALSE      NULL
5   tutoring    2013/01/01   FALSE      2013-2014
```

Here is my first thought.

```
SELECT id, event_name, MIN(actual_date) AS first_day
FROM service_events_view
LEFT JOIN school_placement_view
ON service_events_view.id = school_placement_view.id
WHERE event_name = 'Tutoring' AND WHERE is_noshow <> ‘True’
AND (school_year = '2016-2017' OR school_year IS NULL);
```

From above code, the table will not return id=5 since the school_year of this person is not 2016-2017 or null. Any solutions for this? Thank you!

Comment: Homework?  show us what you have tried

Comment: Your introductory paragraph is contradictory and I can't figure out a simple rule to explain the desired results.

Comment: I have tried the above code which can return the school_year = 2016-2017 and null (missing value). But I also need to have "every person's lasted data" who has enrolled in the tutoring program, even though the school year is not 2016-2017 and null for updating purpose.